# Does the Sonarqube Auth Bitbucket plugin work with Bitbucket Server?

Tags: sonarqube, bitbucket

Does the Sonarqube Auth Bitbucket plugin work with Bitbucket **Server** or only Bitbucket Cloud?
 https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-auth-bitbucket

Answer (score 0):

A pull request has been submitted in order to be able to configure the bitbucket server URL : https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-auth-bitbucket/pull/9

Feel free to test it and to provide feedbacks !